# image not pulling from server HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html

So this problem is a hard one to describe on Google. Long story short, everything seems to be working except the images are not pulling from the server. I've scanned my code up and down, even reviewed a classmate's code and can't find the issue. Any other time I call for the images from the weblab server, they pull, but not here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Slide Show</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<script>
function switchImg(tools){
var t="";
var d="";
document.getElementById("tool").src= t;
document.getElementById("tool").alt= d;
if (tools==1){
    t = "/tools/saw.jpg";
    d = "Saw";
}
else if (tools==2){
    t = "/tools/chisels.jpg";
    d = "Chisels";
}
else if (tools==3){
    t = "/tools/pitchfork.jpg";
    d = "Pitchfork";
}
}
</script>

<style>
img{
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
.buttons{
text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<img id="tool" src="/tools/saw.jpg"  height="248" width="364" alt="Saw"/>


<br/>

<div class="buttons">
<button type="button"  onClick="switchImg(1);"> Saw </button>
<button type="button"  onClick="switchImg(2);"> Chisels </button>
<button type="button"  onClick="switchImg(3);"> Pitchfork </button>
</div>

<br/>




</body>
</html>
```

**Errors**

[image: Broken image on clicks]

[image: Source missing]

Its like the *img* code is not switching the src or alt properly. Was hoping someone here might have a solution, or perhaps its truly something in my code that I'm missing. Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `src` and `alt` after the `if` conditional block:

```
document.getElementById("tool").src = t;
document.getElementById("tool").alt = d;
```

---

Consider using this way:

```js
function switchImg(tools) {
  var t = "";
  var d = "";
  if (tools == 1) {
    t = "/tools/saw.jpg";
    d = "Saw";
  } else if (tools == 2) {
    t = "/tools/chisels.jpg";
    d = "Chisels";
  } else if (tools == 3) {
    t = "/tools/pitchfork.jpg";
    d = "Pitchfork";
  }
  document.getElementById("tool").src = t;
  document.getElementById("tool").alt = d;
}
```

Also, caching the element might improve performance:

```
var img = document.getElementById("tool");
img.src = t;
img.alt = d;
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!! gahhh something that simple of a switch up, 

But let me ask, why does the ```document.getElementById("tool").src/alt = t/d;``` have to come ***AFTER*** the if statement?

Comment: @Snake780 Yes, because you are setting the value first and then only assigning the value. At the point of assigning, it's empty string. You're welcome!  Glad it helped.